# Concept Of Name And ID in PHP & HTML

Tags: php, html

I am doing programming in `PHP and HTML` these days. But the problem I am facing is that many times the data is accepted by the PHP engine using `NAME` attribute used in the HTML syntax of Forms but many times (like when there was a multi-radio button program) `ID` and `NAME` together gave me the required output.

Can anyone here give me a nice explanation of the concept and the difference between these two? I already tried googling but I could not understand.

Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: provide your code so we have a better understanding of what your asking and how to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute is used on form controls (like `<input>`) to associate a known label with a (possibly) variable `value` that will appear in the submitted data. It does not have to be unique, but PHP will only handle multiple fields which share a name properly if that name ends in `[]`.

`<input name="foo" value="bar">` will be available through `$_POST['foo']` or `$_GET['foo']` when the form is submitted.

The `id` attribute can be used on any HTML element so it can be referenced with client side technologies (such as `<label for>`, JavaScript and fragment identifiers in URIs). It does have to be unique.

NB: It is possible to use a name attribute to reference an element with client side technologies, but it is almost always a better idea to use `id` (or `class` for groups of elements) rather then adding a `name` attribute.

Comment: Can we use the `ID` tag only in the forms and then operate on the data using PHP?

Comment: No. The `id` attribute is only for client side use.

Comment: So, there is no use of the `ID` tag in PHP?

Comment: It's not even a matter of use, you just cannot fetch the datas from an id from the server side (using superglobal variables ofc).